# How do I make symbolic links invisible in the Finder?

Tags: terminal, finder

I use `SetFile` via the terminal to render files and folders invisible inside Finder windows. This does not appear to work on symbolic links: the symlink destination is made invisible, rather than the symlink itself.

I see a number of symlinks in `/` which are invisible in the Finder (e.g. `/etc -> private/etc`), so it seems to be possible. Can I duplicate this behavior?

Answer (score 18):

To hide:

```
chflags -h hidden <symlink>
```

To show again:

```
chflags -h nohidden <symlink>
```

Comment: Note that the -h option was only added in Lion. I prefer using chflags, since SetFile only comes with Developer Tools.

Comment: -h      If the file is a symbolic link, change the mode of the link
      itself rather than the file to which it points.

Answer (score 2):

Reading fail.

```
-P                                # perform action on symlink instead of following it
```

This flag has strange indenting in `SetFile -h`, and I must have just ignored it assuming it was related to the `-m` date flag.

So,

```
SetFile -P -a V my_symlink
```

Comment: I got your flag, but it is okay to answer your own question if you find the answer yourself. Just be sure to check the other answers to make sure there isn't one better than your own. No worries.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ln -s source_file target_file` from a terminal you'll get e.g. `/etc -> private/etc` shown in the `ls -la` - but only shown the target_file in the folder.